# What's the difference between MTU and MRU ? How come people talk so often about MTU and little consideration is given to MRU?

Tags: tcp, layer2, mtu

I don't understand why MRU isn't mentioned as frequently as its counterpart MTU. Are they always arranged to have the same value on a device ? A few days ago I noticed that my Windows machine accepted a packet ( 1500 Bytes ) bigger than the current configured MTU ( 1400 ). Could it be related to MRU  ?

Answer (score 1):

By formal definition in [RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791.html#section-3.2), the *maximum transmission unit* is a property directly derived from the underlying link layer's maximum frame size. It is equal to the link layer's maximum payload size. Accordingly, the interface MTU was a unchangeable information parameter.

The desire to cap that payload size in configuration came somewhat later. When tunneling across a certain link layer, the additional headers eat into the payload size. A network designer may want to limit the *practical MTU* for hosts communicating over a tunnel to remove the need for in-path fragmentation. Fragmentation decreases efficiency and creates additional load on the gateways between link layers with different MTUs.

Therefore, the MTU became a configurable item on many platforms. Taken literally, M**T**U just describes the maximum packet size when **t**ransmitting and a host implementation often only limits the size of packets it creates or forwards. Reception may not be limited in the same way, as long as the underlying link layer accepts the transporting frame and passes the contents to the IP stack. In *some* implementations, there's a separate *M**R**U* setting for filtering incoming packets by size. A configurable MRU is not a ubiquitous parameter and mileage will generally vary, given that configurable MTU and MRU values are not formally standardized in any way (AFAIK).

In contrast, a configurable *maximum frame size* on a layer-2 device (switch or NIC) is usually a hard limit, causing oversized frames to be dropped by the hardware.